# if function not communicating with while loop

Tags: python

The purpose of this program is for the user to enter a password which is more than 6 but less than 10 characters and check whether it's strong or weak. Whenever the user inputs an invalid password which has less than 6 or more than 10 characters, it will log it in a text file with a timestamp and displaying a message of the length of the password ("password < 6" or "password > 10"). I did this in my code but for some reason, the it keeps on logging a message saying password should be less than 6 and more than 10 characters. This occurs non-stop in the terminal. Here's the photo and code:

[code issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfmGk.png)

```
from datetime import datetime  # Greyed out until the package is used in the code

print("PasswordChecker1 program developed by Devang Sahani")


def main():
    PASSWORD_LOG_FILE = "password_log_devang_sahani.txt"
    password_log = open(PASSWORD_LOG_FILE, "w").close()
    MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6  # Constant. Variable holding numerical value of minimum password characters
    MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 10  # Constant. Variable holding numerical value of maximum password characters
    message_ls = []  # Content list which will be holding all 'messages'
    message = ''  # This will vary as python choose the appropriate 'message' according to the user input
    password_log = open(PASSWORD_LOG_FILE, "a")

# The while loop prior to the if-structure is a statement to control the flow of loops. Whilst it stays true, it
# will loop constantly until the statement results false causing it to break the program. In this case, the program will
# loop until user inputs a password with requirements of minimum and maximum characters.

# The if-structure below allows python to use a range of tools for different tasks that is asked within the code. This
# includes tools like the 'isalpha()' or 'isnumeric()' method, which are used below in the structure as it allows python
# check whether the inputted password is all letter or numbers and present the following:

    while True:  # While Loop
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")  # Prompts user to enter password
        password_length = len(password)  # Variable which holds the password character length
        print(password_length)  # Prints the password length of 'password' to inform user
        current_date_and_time = datetime.today()

        while len(password) < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH or len(password) > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH: # Checks requirement constants

            if password_length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
                # If requirements are not met, it says this
                reason_password_invalid = "Password < 6. Should have more than 6 but less 10 characters"
                message = reason_password_invalid
                password_log.write(f"{current_date_and_time}, {message}\n")
            elif password_length > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
                reason_password_invalid = "Password > 6. Should have more than 6 but less 10 characters"
                message = reason_password_invalid
                password_log.write(f"{current_date_and_time}, {message}\n")
                # If input password meets requirement, it will move on and check if it's all alphabetical
            elif password.isalpha():
                # If yes, then it will display this message and loop
                reason_password_invalid = "password weak – contains only letters"
                message = reason_password_invalid
                password_log.write(f"{current_date_and_time}, {message}\n")
                # If password is not all alphabetical letters, it will use this function to check
            elif password.isnumeric():
                # And if true, it will display this message and loop
                reason_password_invalid = "password weak – contains only numbers"
                message = reason_password_invalid
                password_log.write(f"{current_date_and_time}, {message}\n")
                # If the input is not all alphabetical or numerical, it will move to this else statement
            else:
                # And choose this message
                message = "password strong"
            # Out of all 'message' in the list, it will choose the appropriate one
            message_ls.append(message)
            # And print it here
            print(message)

            # If the print result is this, it will break the code that will end the program
            if message == "password strong":
                print(f"\n Validation Successful. Your password is {password_length} characters.")

                print(f"\n{message}\n")
                password_log = open(PASSWORD_LOG_FILE, "r")

                for x in password_log:
                    print(x, end='')

                break
                password_log.close()


main()
```

Comment: If the password length is in range, then you won't be checking any other requirements (like the `isalpha` or `isnumeric` tests). And you won't even save the password anywhere. And if the password length is out of range, and doesn't fulfill one of the criteria, you don't ask for a new password, you just keep on looping checking the exact same password over and over again.

Comment: What is the question? where do you think the probem is?

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to *debug* it? Like using a debugger to actually step through the code statement by statement to make sure it's working?

Comment: I believe the problem is after I placed an if statement under the while loop. this was because I wanted the program to display a message informing the user that their password was under 6 or over 10 characters (timestamp, password<6 or <10. Should have more than 6 but less than 10 characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can only enter the second while if your password is weak and you can't reintroduce it so it will keep using the first password you entered and saying that is weak.

You should let the user introduce the password again at the end of the second while and put the if message == "password strong" outside the while.

I think something like this would work:

```
while True:  # While Loop
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")  # Prompts user to enter password
    password_length = len(password)  # Variable which holds the password character length
    print(password_length)  # Prints the password length of 'password' to inform user
    current_date_and_time = datetime.today()

    while password_length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH or password_length > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH or password.isalpha() or password.isnumeric(): # Checks requirement constants

        if password_length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
            # If requirements are not met, it says this
            reason_password_invalid = "Password < 6. Should have more than 6 but less 10 characters"
            message = reason_password_invalid
            password_log.write(f"{current_date_and_time}, {message}\n")
        elif password_length > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
            reason_password_invalid = "Password > 6. Should have more than 6 but less 10 characters"
            message = reason_password_invalid
            password_log.write(f"{current_date_and_time}, {message}\n")
            # If input password meets requirement, it will move on and check if it's all alphabetical
        elif password.isalpha():
            # If yes, then it will display this message and loop
            reason_password_invalid = "password weak – contains only letters"
            message = reason_password_invalid
            password_log.write(f"{current_date_and_time}, {message}\n")
            # If password is not all alphabetical letters, it will use this function to check
        elif password.isnumeric():
            # And if true, it will display this message and loop
            reason_password_invalid = "password weak – contains only numbers"
            message = reason_password_invalid
            password_log.write(f"{current_date_and_time}, {message}\n")
            # If the input is not all alphabetical or numerical, it will move to this else statement
        # Out of all 'message' in the list, it will choose the appropriate one
        message_ls.append(message)
        # And print it here
        print(message)

        # If the print result is this, it will break the code that will end the program
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")  # Prompts user to enter password
        password_length = len(password)


    print(f"\n Validation Successful. Your password is {password_length} characters.")

    print(f"\n{message}\n")
    password_log = open(PASSWORD_LOG_FILE, "r")

    for x in password_log:
        print(x, end='')

    break
    password_log.close()
```